# Как сравнить слова в разных фалах?

Tags: c, text

Всем привет! Изучая си путем выдумки заданий и их осуществления я столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть два текстовых файла, проблема в том что я не знаю как слова которые есть в обоих файлах вывести, к примеру, на экран. Ну, вывести то я знаю как)) а вот правильно сравнить...

Вот вместимое файлов:
[image: Изображение 1]

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char string [ 32 ];

int wordsCounter ( const char *name_of_file );

int main ( const int const argc, const char const **argv )
{
    // Get number of words
    int length = wordsCounter ( argv[2] );
    fprintf ( stdout, "\n[*]Number of words is %d\n\n", length );

    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        fprintf ( stdout, "[!]Invalid aruments\n" );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

        FILE *ff, *sf, *tf;
        string ch; string ch2;

        // FIRST FILE
        if ( ( ff = fopen ( argv[1], "r" ) ) == NULL ) 
        {
            fprintf ( stdout, "[!]First file do not found\n" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }   
        fprintf ( stdout, "[*]First file was open.\n" );

        // SECOND FILE
        if ( (sf = fopen ( argv[2], "r" )) == NULL ) 
        {
            fprintf ( stdout, "[!]Second file do not found\n" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        fprintf ( stdout, "[*]Second file was open.\n" );

        // THIRD FILE
        if ( (tf = fopen ( "file_known.txt", "r" )) == NULL ) 
        {
            fprintf ( stdout, "[!]File \"known.txt\" do not found\n" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }   
        fprintf ( stdout, "[*]Known file was open.\n\n" );

        // COMPARING
     -->for( int i = 0; i < length && !feof(ff) && !feof(sf); i++ )
     -->{
     -->    fscanf(ff, "%s", ch);
     -->    fscanf(sf, "%s", ch2);

     -->    if( strcmp( ch, ch2 ) == 0 )
     -->    { fprintf( stdout, "%s\n", ch ); }
     -->}

        fclose ( ff );
        fclose ( sf );
        fclose ( tf );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// WORDS COUNTER
int wordsCounter ( const char *name_of_file )
{
    int length = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen( name_of_file, "r" );

    string ch;

    while ( !feof(fp) )
    {
        fscanf( fp, "%31s", ch );
        length++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return length;
}
```

Результаты:[image: Изображение 2]

А должно выводить все одинаковые слова, а совпадения игнорировать. В даном случае дожно вывести слова: The, my, are, и speak, в вывило только The.

Comment: Тут можно либо использовать хэш-таблицу в которую помещаете слова из первого (или меньшего по размеру) файла и ищете в ней слова из второго, либо сортируете слова файлов, а потом выбираете одинаковые, последовательно просматривая  массивы этих слов.

Comment: Не могу понять, в чем же моя ошибка?

Comment: Вы в цикле сравниваете первое слово первого файла с первым словом второго файла, затем вторые слова из них и т.д. Первые слова в них -- `The` - да, печатаете, видимо остальные попарно не совпадают. А чего вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: Верно подметили. Уже исправил.